# jquery selector does not work inside jqueryTemplate

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

does anyone know why this jquery selector is not working when I use it within a template: (BTW I know jQTemplates is deprecated)

```
var selector2 = $('ul').find('li');
```

--

```
<script id="tmpGallery" type="text/html">
    {{if showImage(this)}}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://farm${farm}.static.flickr.com/${server}/${id}_${secret}.jpg">
            <img alt="Historicats" src="http://farm${farm}.static.flickr.com/${server}/${id}_${secret}.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    {{/if}}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showImage(image){
    var selector2 = $('ul').find('li');
    //console.dir(selector2);
    //console.log("selector2 :"+selector2.length);
    return true;
}
</script>
```

you can run the code at: http://jsfiddle.net/mescalito2345/C6T7v/3/

any solution? please!

Comment: What does `this` point to in your code? What are you expecting?

Comment: the real code is to complex to explain, but I need to evaluate if "li" elements reach to 10, I'm planing to implement Lazy Loading at that point... but any way, how can I select with jQuery inside showImage() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change `showImage(this)` to `showImage()` because `this` you are not using any parameter that is passed to `showImage`.

Based on your fiddle code, you need to use something like this.

```
$(function() {
    $.each(images, function(i, img){
        $("#tmpGallery").tmpl(img).appendTo("#gallery");
    });
});
```

Change `showImage` as below which will return true until li elements become 10

```
function showImage(){
    return $('ul').find('li').length <= 10;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C6T7v/17/